Uniform bound for a integral
Consider the following integral
$$\int_0^t (1+t-s)^{-\alpha}(1+s)^{-\beta}ds,\alpha,\beta>0.$$
Clearly there is no singularity at the origin and so this integral has an upper bound, which we denote as $C_t$. I want to figure out under what restriction for $\alpha, \beta$ such that this bound is independent of $t$?

What have you tried?

Mathematica:  $\fbox{$\frac{(t+1)^{1-\beta } , _2F_1\left(1,-\alpha -\beta +2;2-\alpha
;\frac{1}{t+2}\right)-(t+1)^{1-\alpha } , _2F_1\left(1,-\alpha -\beta +2;2-\alpha
;\frac{t+1}{t+2}\right)}{(\alpha -1) (t+2)}\text{ if }\alpha >0\land \beta >0\land
(t\notin \mathbb{R}\lor \Re(t)>-1)$}$ which suggests there will always be a $t$ dependence.

Assuming that $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $t$ are all positive, using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$I=\int (1+t-s)^{-\alpha}(1+s)^{-\beta}\,ds$$
$$I=\frac{1}{(1-\alpha ) t}(1-s)^{1-\beta } (-s+t+1)^{1-\alpha }~~\times $$ $$ \,
   _2F_1\left(1,-\alpha -\beta +2;2-\alpha
   ;\frac{t-s+1}{t}\right)$$ So, the definite integral
$$J(t)=\int_0^t (1+t-s)^{-\alpha}(1+s)^{-\beta}\,ds=\frac{1}{(1-\alpha ) t}~~\times $$
$$\Bigg((t+1)^{1-\alpha } \, _2F_1\left(1,-\alpha -\beta
   +2;2-\alpha
   ;1+\frac{1}{t}\right)-$$ $$(1-t)^{1-\beta } \,
   _2F_1\left(1,-\alpha -\beta +2;2-\alpha
   ;\frac{1}{t}\right)\Bigg)$$
If $t\leq 1$ (which is simpler to analyze)
$$J(t)=(-1)^{\beta }\, t^{-\alpha -\beta +1}
   \left(B_{1+\frac{1}{t}}(1-\alpha ,1-\beta
   )-B_{\frac{1}{t}}(1-\alpha ,1-\beta )\right)$$
Expanding as series around $t=0$
$$J(t)=t \left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1) ^n\,\frac{P_n}{(n+1)!}\,t^n\right)$$
where the first coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & P(n)  \\
 1 & -\beta +\alpha  \\
 2 & \left(\beta ^2+\beta \right)+\alpha  (1-\beta)+\alpha ^2 \\
 3 & -\beta  \left(\beta ^2+3 \beta
   +2\right)+\alpha  \left(\beta
   ^2+2\right)+\alpha ^2 (3-\beta )+\alpha^3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Much more tedious is the case where $t>1$ but the conclusion is the same (@DavidG.Stork already give it in comments) : it does not seem that $J(t)$ could be independent of $t$.
